# Azure API Management doesn't validate certificates chain

Tags: azure, ssl, certificate, azure-api-management

I want to secure my services using Azure API Management Resource and a client certificate.

According to the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates), I uploaded my self-signed root certificate in CA Certificate as Root.

Inside API policies, I'm asking for the certificate validation:

```
        <when condition="@(!context.Request.Certificate.VerifyNoRevocation())">
            <return-response>
                <set-status code="403" reason="Not verified certificate" />
            </return-response>
        </when>
```

The Root CA is not the issuer of the client cert: I have two intermediates CA:
`Root => Inter1 => Inter2 => Client`

So I provide the chain, using `curl`.

```
curl --cert-type pem --cacert full-chain.pem --cert user.crt --key user.key https://my-api-management-url -i
```

But APIM doesn't seem to use the provided chain to validate it against the uploaded Root CA. The only time I could passed the check was when I put the `Inter2` as CA Certificate in APIM.

There is a setting to allow APIM to use the provided chain or does APIM can only check if the CA is the issuer of the client certificate?

*For information, the chain is valid when I try to call a NginX server with the same Root CA and the same curl command (just changing URL, of course).*

Comment: The policy `VerifyNoRevocation` indicates the verification against a CRL/CDP and/or OCSP. As you write **self-signed** I guess nothing like this is in place, right?

Comment: In the documentation you've provided, at the bottom there's this part:
`If you are using self-signed certificates, you will need to disable certificate chain validation in order for API Management to communicate with the backend system. Otherwise it will return a 500 error code. To configure this, you can use the New-AzApiManagementBackend (for new back end) or Set-AzApiManagementBackend (for existing back end) PowerShell cmdlets and set the -SkipCertificateChainValidation parameter to True.`
Doesn't that mean, that you just can't verify the chain yet?

Comment: @DanielFisherlennybacon It wouldn't validate with Inter2.

Answer (score 0):

you must make sure that your root and intermediate certificates are uploaded separately. also your host certificate has the check activated to negotiate certificate this will enable your verification policy